# Can be connected JavaERP to android?

Tags: android

Is there any procedure to connect JavaERP web application running on remote server to android application?
basically all i'm thinking to do is like there is an ERP having a user account existing in its database, and all the records of self in ERP, now the user can login with his android application to his particular account and get his basic details and records.
if YES then how?

Comment: Do you mean Enterprise Resource Planning for ERP?

Comment: Write a webservice and connect from Android App to Web application. It is as simple as that.

Comment: yes its Enterprise Resource Planning @Tiny

Comment: thanks a lot @AlokNair :) Happieee Coding